# Byte inserted between two other bytes when sending byte array over http

Tags: arrays, http, byte

I'm busy setting up communication between a ESP and a nodejs server, sending data in bytes between the two. But every time I send these 3 bytes in order over http I receive an extra byte between two. I've tested this with Postman and my Nodejs server but get the same result on both.
So when I send "00000000 10010100 01110000" over http I get on wireshark and on my ESP "00000000 11000010 10010100 01110000". Can Anyone help clarify why this happens?

Ive tried changing the values and the problem stops, removing or adding another byte sometimes helps but not if these 3 bytes are in order.

Answer (score 0):

Oky I think I found my problem and correct me if I understood this incorrectly. 
Byte is unsigned datatype ranging 0 to 255, char is a signed datatype ranging -128 to 127. So my value was greater than 127 so overflow occurs.